# Trying to backup sql file with mysqldump with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to backup my database into a specific folder, but it doesn't execute. Here's the code I am using.

```
   
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $host = "localhost";
        $databasename ="act2";
        $path = "‪D:/xampp/htdocs/activity2/Database/act2.sql";
        $backup = exec('D:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump --user=' .$username. '--password=' .$password. '--host' .$host. '' .$databasename. '>' .$path. '');

        if(isset($_POST['backup'])){
            if(file_exists($path)){
                echo "backup success";
                echo "<br>";
            }else{
                echo "backup failed";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

I do not get any PHP error, but I am getting the "Backup failed" message .

Comment: echon you strung and try it directly in a cmd window  you are missing some spacces`$backup = exec('D:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump --user=' .$username. ' --password=' .$password. ' --host' .$host. ' ' .$databasename. ' > ' .$path. '');`

Comment: You really should not be using php to execute a command line tool...

Comment: @Shadow it's a school requirement tho. professor showed it to us and it's working. idk why it keeps giving me false.

Comment: Do some debugging then. Put `echo 'D:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump --user=' .$username. '--password=' .$password. '--host' .$host. '' .$databasename. '>' .$path. '';` in the code and get the full command. Then copy/paste that into a terminal (running under the same user account as your PHP runs under - it probably isn't the same as your personal account) and see if you get an errors.

Comment: Alternatively / additionally, specify an argument for the "output" arg to the `exec` command (see the manual for details: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and capture the output that way.